# How to convert SVG in HTML to PNG?

Tags: html, css, svg, png

I have a logo that is saved as an svg in my assets folder as logo.html.

Below is the svg

```
<svg class="f2" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 69 15" style="enable-background:new 0 0 69 15;" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
        <g id="COS_Re-sell_logo">
            <path id="Fill-1" class="st0" d="M1.9,4.9v2.2c0.6-1,1.5-2.4,2.9-2.4c0.3,0,1.1,0,2.3,1.1l-1,1.6C5.8,7.2,5,6.5,4.2,6.5
                            c-0.7,0-2.3,0.8-2.3,2.9v5H0V4.9H1.9" />
            <path id="Fill-3" class="st0" d="M14.7,8.7c0-0.4-0.2-2.4-2.3-2.4c-0.6,0-1.3,0.2-1.8,0.8C10.1,7.7,10,8.3,10,8.7H14.7z
                            M16.4,13.5c-0.6,0.4-1.7,1.1-3.7,1.1c-1,0-2.1-0.1-3.2-1.3C8.2,12,8,10.5,8,9.6c0-3,1.8-4.9,4.4-4.9c2.2,0,3.7,1.6,4,3.7
                            c0.1,0.6,0.1,1.1,0.1,1.4H9.9c0.1,1.4,1,3,3,3c1.2,0,2.4-0.4,3.4-1.2V13.5L16.4,13.5z" />
            <polygon id="Fill-4" class="st0" points="19.1,10.2 42.5,10.2 42.5,9 19.1,9      " />
            <path id="Fill-5" class="st0" d="M50.6,7.4c-1-0.7-1.8-1-2.7-1c-0.9,0-1.2,0.5-1.2,0.9c0,0.6,0.7,1,2,1.7C50,9.7,51,10.7,51,12
                            c0,0.9-0.7,2.7-3.2,2.7c-1.3,0-2.2-0.4-3.1-0.9v-2c1.3,0.9,2.5,1.3,3,1.3c0.6,0,1.4-0.3,1.4-1c0-0.7-0.6-1-1.4-1.5
                            c-1.6-0.9-2.9-1.7-2.9-3.3c0-1.4,1.2-2.5,3-2.5c1.4,0,2.4,0.6,2.9,0.8V7.4" />
            <path id="Fill-6" class="st0" d="M59.4,8.7c0-0.4-0.2-2.4-2.3-2.4c-0.6,0-1.3,0.2-1.8,0.8c-0.5,0.6-0.6,1.1-0.6,1.6H59.4z
                            M61,13.5c-0.6,0.4-1.7,1.1-3.7,1.1c-1,0-2.1-0.1-3.2-1.3c-1.2-1.3-1.4-2.8-1.4-3.7c0-3,1.8-4.9,4.4-4.9c2.2,0,3.7,1.6,4,3.7
                            c0.1,0.6,0.1,1.1,0.1,1.4h-6.6c0.1,1.4,1,3,3,3c1.2,0,2.4-0.4,3.4-1.2V13.5L61,13.5z" />
            <polygon id="Fill-9" class="st0" points="67.1,14.4 69,14.4 69,0 67.1,0      " />
            <polygon id="Fill-8" class="st0" points="63.1,14.4 65,14.4 65,0 63.1,0      " />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

How do I change it into a png and stick this logo in the header of my website ?

Comment: Save as `.svg`, then open on illustrator and save it in png - https://imgur.com/a/SsItueO

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 4):

You can do it here with that code

```
<script>
(function(w,d) {
   'use strict';

   var btn = d.querySelector( 'button' );
   var svg = d.querySelector( 'svg' );
   var canvas = d.querySelector( 'canvas' );

   var imageName ='your-image-name';

function triggerDownload ( imgURI ) {
   var evt = new MouseEvent( 'click', {
       view: w,
       bubbles: false,
       cancelable: true
    });

   var a = d.createElement( 'a' );
       a.setAttribute( 'download', imageName + '.png' );
       a.setAttribute( 'href', imgURI );
       a.setAttribute( 'target', 'blank' );
       a.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

   btn.addEventListener( 'click', function () {

   var ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
   var data = ( new XMLSerializer() ).serializeToString( svg );
   var DOMURL = w.URL || w.webkitURL || w;

   var img = new Image();
   var svgBlob = new Blob( [data], { type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8' } );
   var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL( svgBlob );

   img.onload = function () {
       ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
       DOMURL.revokeObjectURL( url );

    var imgURI = canvas
        .toDataURL( 'image/png' )
        .replace( 'image/png', 'image/octet-stream' );

    triggerDownload( imgURI );
  };
    img.src = url;
    d.querySelector( 'h2' ).classList.remove( 'hide' );
 });
}(window, document));
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x4okm30f/

Source: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/converting-an-svg-path-to-a-png/279026/9

I would also like to add that you should consider keeping your image in svg format as you have the best quality for the minimum size and by putting directly the code in the html, you also don't have to load another file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an online tool, I let you find the right one by googling something like "SVG to PNG" and then include your png with `<img src="images/logo.png" alt="Your logo">`

Comment: I googled and found a few online tools. Does it work if I just upload the logo.html file as is ?

Comment: No. Save only the `<svg>...</svg>` part in a logo.svg file